# After installing sql 2012 express, visual studio started to give run time error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2010 proffesional.

I have started to take errors after installing sql 2012 express.

I did the instructions here :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/59147ba0-82d2-418a-a33d-08f75eb68387

(

1.Remove Visual Studio 2010 Sp1 manually from control panel

2.Remove Visual Studio 2010 with this tool http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall

and this command:Complete (VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full /netfx)
)

Also i deleted all user data and every folder about visual studio and installed again.
I have removed all add-ins.

But the result is the same.

Here are the errors:

[image: errors]

[Here is the log file (ActivityLog.xml)](http://www.seckindurgay.com/activitylog.rar) 
How can i correct this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at regkey

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ExtensionManager\EnabledExtensions
```

I removed an entry with a lot of question marks: `??????????????????`
All started working fine then.